# Start multiple processes via npm scripts using PM2

Tags: node.js, npm, pm2

I want to start multiple processes by `pm2`.

I found how to start one process for `npm run start`:

```
pm2 start npm -- start
```

But when I've tried make something like `pm2 start npm -- event` for `npm run event` it doesn't start a new process but restarts the first one.

How can I start multiple process by `npm` and `pm2`?

Comment: Does `pm2 start npm -- run event` work?

Comment: no ( the same as early

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`--name` flag](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/#cheat-sheet) to give each processes a unique name for PM2 to identify them by.

For example:

```
pm2 start --name=start npm -- start
pm2 start --name=event npm -- run event
```

Further operations should use the `name` you have given each process. For example to stop them:

```
pm2 stop start
pm2 stop event
```